# Error:Unable to start the daemon process

Tags: android

Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/1.12/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

### Please read below process output to find out more:

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open up your System Properties

   - On the left sidebar, click Advanced System Settings
   - Click Environment Variables
   - Under System Variables, Click New and enter these values
     Variable name:  _JAVA_OPTIONS
     variable value:  -Xmx524M
2. Start Android Studio.

   - Go to File and Click Close Project and Welcome window will open
   - Go to Configure > Settings
     On Settings dialog,select Compiler from left and set VM Options to -Xmx512m(i.e. write -Xmx512m under VM Options:) and press OK.
3. Delete the .gradle directory (usually at C:\Users\YourUserName.gradle). If you dont locate it there, go to File, click on Settings and enter "gradle" in the search box and you will locate your ".gradle" directory. Delete it
4. Restart Android Studio